# Can't use Redux connect() correctly with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using Redux with Typescript, and I can't pass data between Components.

EmpList.tsx

```
function mapStateToProps(){//mapping here}
.... //body of a Component
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmpList)
```

Tool.tsx

```
import EmpList from './EmpList'
....
private empListTemp: RefObject<EmpList> = createRef()
```

The problem is that I get an error in the **Tool.tsx** *'EmpList refers to a value but is being used as a type here'.*
Now, If I remove `connect(mapStateToProps)` from **export**, or put `export{mapStateToProps, EmpList}` in the **EmpList.tsx**, I don't have that error anymore, but obviously Redux won't work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`forwardRef: boolean`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#forwardref-boolean) to the options of `connect` for the `ref` to have any significant effect - and then you use the type of your unconnected component, since you want to "ref" the "inner component", not the function component wrapper created by `connect`.
You would still *use* the connected component itself though.

Comment: I think I didn't understan where to use "typeof".. like this?:  private empListTemp: RefObject<typeof EmpList> = createRef()     sry, I'm new to all of this, and Redux just got my limited knowledge of React and Ts get even more limited

Comment: No `typeof`. The *unconnected component*. So not what you are at the moment exporting as the `default` eport (that is your store-connected component - your original component that you want to access the ref to is actually "wrapped inside another component here"). Do `export { EmpList as UnconnectedEmpList }`, import that and use this as the generic for the ref.

Comment: Oh man, you can't imagine how much you've helped me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-useselector-hook) and [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-usedispatch-hook) hook